# Gurus that teach Attainment of Siddhis (super-powers)

Tags: siddhi

Are there any gurus living today that claim to teach people how to attain siddhis (super-powers) that have been provided in Patanjali's Yoga Sutra?  Or are there no such gurus left in the world?

Comment: That you have to find out urself.. When ur time comes ur Guru will certainly approach u.. BTW looking for a Guru for achieving only Siddhis is a Tamasik + Rajasik approach..So not recommended...but its ur choice..

Comment: ask in mutts, ashrams or veda patashalas

Comment: @Rickross Can't superpowers be used for humanities greater good?

Comment: Yes siddhis can definitely be used for the benefit of mankind.. Most Siddha Yogis exactly do that.